# How to combine manipulate graph with listplot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am trying to simulate Jiles Atherton model with my experimental data,but I am not able to combine the simulated one with experimental one.
I am getting the error "could not combine the graphics objects in show"

Below is the code used .Really appreciate any assistance

```
dataInput = Import["C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\JA.TEST.DAT"];
data = dataInput[[All, {1, 2}]]
p2 = ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {{-7000, 7000}, {-1, 1}}]

\[Mu]0 = 4 \[Pi] 10^-7;
 \[Omega] = 2 \[Pi] (1);
Man[t_] := 
 Ms (Coth[(H[t] + \[Alpha] M[t])/a] - a/(H[t] + \[Alpha] M[t]))
\[Delta]M[t_] = 
 1 - UnitStep[-H'[t]] UnitStep[Man[t] - M[t]] - 
  UnitStep[H'[t]] UnitStep[M[t] - Man[t]]; 
H[t_] := 7000 Sin[\[Omega] t]
\[Delta][t_] := Sign[H'[t]]
solns = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Block[{Ms, c, a, k, \[Alpha]}, 
     M'[t] == (\[Delta]M[t] (Man[t] - M[t]) H'[t] + 
         c k \[Delta][t] Man'[t])/(k \[Delta][t] - \[Alpha] \[Delta]M[
           t] (Man[t] - M[t]))], M[10^-3] == 0}, 
   M, {t, 0, 5}, {Ms, c, a, k, \[Alpha]}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
p1 = Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[{H[t], 10^-6 solns[Ms, c, a, k, \[Alpha]][t]}, {t, 0,
     1.3}, AxesLabel -> {Row[{Style["H", Italic], " (A/m)"}], 
     Row[{Style["B", Italic], " (T)"}]}, LabelStyle -> {15}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-7000, 7000}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 1.125 {400, 400}],
  Row[{"saturation magnetization ", 
    Subscript[Style["M", Italic], "s"], " (A/m)"}],
  {{Ms, 1. 10^6, "" }, 0.5 10^6, 1.1 10^6, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
   ImageSize -> Tiny}, "",
  Row[{"magnetization reversibility ", Style["c", Italic]}],
  {{c, 1/5.5, ""}, 1/30, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
   ImageSize -> Tiny}, "",
  Row[{"domain wall density ", Style["a", Italic], " (A/m)"}],
  {{a, 1800, ""}, 1000, 2300, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
   ImageSize -> Tiny}, "",
  Row[{"average energy to \nbreak pinning site ", Style["k", Italic], 
    " (A/m)"}],
  {{k, 2000, ""}, 1000, 2500, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
   ImageSize -> Tiny}, "",
  "interdomain coupling \[Alpha] ",
  {{\[Alpha], 2.1 10^-3, ""}, 1.1 10^-3, 5.1 10^-3, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Tiny},
  ContinuousAction -> False, SaveDefinitions -> True, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
Manipulate[Show[p1, p2], PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Your code currently pulls data from your hard drive.  We can't access it.   Please supply some accessible data set or some way to generate a data set for the purposes of running this code.

Comment: Your last line of code `Manipulate[Show[p1, p2], PlotRange -> Automatic]` does not conform to a Manipulate.  It specifies no controls.  `PlotRange -> Automatic` is not a option for `Manipulate`.  Not clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your link in the comment does not give a clear direction to access your data, I offer the following as a structural approach to what I think you want to achieve.

```
 \[Mu]0 = 4 \[Pi] 10^-7;
    \[Omega] = 2 \[Pi] (1);
    Man[t_] := 
     Ms (Coth[(H[t] + \[Alpha] M[t])/a] - 
        a/(H[t] + \[Alpha] M[t])); \[Delta]M[t_] = 
     1 - UnitStep[-H'[t]] UnitStep[Man[t] - M[t]] - 
      UnitStep[H'[t]] UnitStep[M[t] - Man[t]]; 
    H[t_] := 7000 Sin[\[Omega] t]; \[Delta][t_] := Sign[H'[t]];
    solns = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Block[{Ms, c, a, k, \[Alpha]}, 
         M'[t] == (\[Delta]M[t] (Man[t] - M[t]) H'[t] + 
             c k \[Delta][t] Man'[t])/(k \[Delta][t] - \[Alpha] \[Delta]M[
               t] (Man[t] - M[t]))], M[10^-3] == 0}, 
       M, {t, 0, 5}, {Ms, c, a, k, \[Alpha]}, 
       Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];

   dataInput = Import["C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\JA.TEST.DAT"];
   data = dataInput[[All, {1, 2}]];
    
    Manipulate[
     Show[
      ParametricPlot[{H[t], 10^-6 solns[Ms, c, a, k, \[Alpha]][t]}, {t, 0,
         1.3},
       AxesLabel -> {Row[{Style["H", Italic], " (A/m)"}], 
         Row[{Style["B", Italic], " (T)"}]},
       LabelStyle -> {15},
       PlotRange -> {{-7000, 7000}, {-1, 1}},
       PlotStyle -> Black,
       AspectRatio -> 1,
       ImageSize -> 1.125 {400, 400}],
      
      ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
         PlotRange -> {{-7000, 7000}, {-1, 1}}]
  
      ],
     Row[{"saturation magnetization ",
       Subscript[Style["M", Italic], "s"], " (A/m)"}], {{Ms, 1. 10^6, ""},
       0.5 10^6, 1.1 10^6,
      Appearance -> "Labeled",
      ImageSize -> Tiny}, "",
     Row[{"magnetization reversibility ",
       Style["c", Italic]}], {{c, 1/5.5, ""}, 1/30, 1,
      Appearance -> "Labeled",
      ImageSize -> Tiny}, "",
     Row[{"domain wall density ",
       Style["a", Italic], " (A/m)"}], {{a, 1800, ""}, 1000, 2300,
      Appearance -> "Labeled",
      ImageSize -> Tiny}, "",
     Row[{"average energy to \nbreak pinning site ", Style["k", Italic], 
       " (A/m)"}], {{k, 2000, ""}, 1000, 2500,
      Appearance -> "Labeled",
      ImageSize -> 
       Tiny}, "", "interdomain coupling \[Alpha] ", {{\[Alpha], 2.1 10^-3,
        ""}, 1.1 10^-3, 5.1 10^-3,
      Appearance -> "Labeled",
      ImageSize -> Tiny},
     ContinuousAction -> False,
     SaveDefinitions -> True,
     ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

The above code sets your variables and defines functions the code later uses then retrieves your experimental data.

A `Manipulate` follows.  The `Manipulate` manilpulates a `Show`.  The `Show` has two plots, corresponding to your original `p1` & `p2`.

Comment: Sorry I shared the wrong folder for data .This code worked and this is what I was looking for. Thank you so much....!